# how to load image from project file present in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Can you please tell me how to load an image present in resources i have tried in many ways its not working.

```
if(s0.equals("about Calculator")){
        String message = "My Calculator \ncopyright @ 2014 sravanthi\n";
        ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/calculator.png"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,   icon);
}
```

project structure:

```
 awt|->src->defaultpackage->program
    |->resources->calculator.png
```

Comment: and what issue did you face?

Comment: You need to make sure that the directory containing the resources is within the projects class and build paths

Comment: show your project structure.

Comment: Not sure that `resources` should be maintained within the `src` directory, but should be in the `awt` directory and included within eclipses class/build paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse's Java project know the concept of a [*build path*](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm). These are the libraries and folders where the compiler will look for resources when building the project.

Additionally - and that is important here - all resources inside the build path will also make up the *class path* of the running program when being invoked from Eclipse.

The source folder (default is simply `src`) is automatically part of that build path. All compiled class files will be put into a directory called `bin` which in turn will be part of the class path.

Now you can add additional folders to that build path if they aren't already part of it. Simply right-click your folder `resources`, click on "Build Path", then on "Use as Source Folder". (Alternative: In the project properties, you can "Add Class Folder" in the Java Build Path -> Libraries tab.)

The effect is that all files in that resources folder will now be copied also to the bin directory, so the running program has all those files in its class path.